# What happens when computer output res is too high?

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card

lets say I have a computer running Win 7 and the res is 1920x1080. Now i shut down the computer then replace the monitor with one whose max res is 1024x768. What would happen? would the computer default to that resolution or try to output 1920x1080 and present you with a blank screen of somesort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not display, your monitor would probably say no signal detected or it would just be blank.

Just tested this on my external monitor with the Intel graphics utility, it just didn't display, it says no signal detected until the setting reverts back after 20 seconds.

Comment: This really depends on the monitor and video hardware; if it sees a different EDID with a different max resolution it's liable to display the correct one on its own under Win7.  If your setup can't do this or doesn't send this information, that's when you'll get a blank screen.  Basically 'either it'll fix itself or it'll do this but there's no blanket answer'.

Comment: Very true @shinrai it may act differently on other monitors. maybe we should flag as subjective? I was using a Samsung 22" if it matters to anyone...

Comment: Yup, some monitors also say "out of range".

Comment: ahh i see, but there would no permanent damage to said monitor right?